# Can't insert blob image using Python via stored procedure mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert an image into a **blob column** in mysql using stored procedure.

**Python code:**

```
from mysql.connector import pooling

conn_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="PipelinePool", pool_size=5, **DB_CONFIG)
conn = conn_pool.get_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    image = image_file.read()
    cursor.callproc('INSERT_IMG', args=(image))
    conn.commit()
```

`cursor.callproc('INSERT_IMG', args=(image))` But this line produces an error:

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed calling stored routine; 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

**Stored procedure code:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERT_IMG` (IN _image BLOB)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO some_table (IMAGE) VALUE (_image);
END
```

Comment: Why do you have a stored procedure for a trivial `INSERT` statement?

Comment: You need to supply your image in `BINARY` encoding. UTF-8 will not work. You may want to try hex-encoding it as per [MySQL notation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) as that avoids the binary problem altogether. Remember, storing large chunks of binary data in a database is often a world of hurt and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As per tadman's comment.

I have to send hex string as an argument.

```
from mysql.connector import pooling
import binascii

conn_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="PipelinePool", pool_size=5, **DB_CONFIG)
conn = conn_pool.get_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    image = image_file.read()
    cursor.callproc('INSERT_IMG', args=(binascii.hexlify(image)))
    conn.commit()
```

Then in the stored procedure, I convert the hex string to binary by using `UNHEX()`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERT_IMG` (IN _image BLOB)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO some_table (IMAGE) VALUE (UNHEX(_image));
END
```